# PGFPlots: Change the color of axis lines

Tags: pgfplots

I want to change the color of the axis lines only without changing the color of the axis labels, tick labels etc.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%
\begin{document}
%
  \pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={%
      red 
    }   
  }
%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        xlabel={X},
        ylabel={Y}
      ]%  
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

I am not aware of a `pgfkey` for axis lines only along the lines of `/pgfplots/tick style`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can set the axis labels and tick labels independently, but as Jake notes in the comments, you can also just set the `axis line` style.  I've modified your example to show all three

```
\documentclass[png,border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%
  \pgfplotsset{
    axis line style={red},
    every axis label/.append style ={blue},
    every tick label/.append style={green}  
  }
%

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        xlabel={X},
        ylabel={Y}
      ]%  
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: +1 how about moving `pgfplotsset` to the preamble? :)

Comment: You could also use the key `axis line style=red` to only turn the axis lines red. That way, you don't have to look up all the styles required to turn things back to black.

Comment: @Jake Thanks.  I should have left this to the experts.  I'll updated my answer.