# Any piste to replicate this oscillogram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, plot

[image: oscillogramme]

I need to replicate this oscillogram using LaTeX. I know a bit of TiKZ but I would like to have some tips or packages to get started building this and at the end come up my own to draw others like this.

```
$u(t) = 8\cos(400\pi t)$ and $i(t) = 0,2\cos(400\pi t - \dfrac{2\pi}{5})$ are examples.
```

Comment: My first thought was to use `pgfplots`. Do you have the functions of those two curves?

Comment: Sine, with exponentially decreasing amplitudes.

Comment: Oscilloscope: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/textronics-oscilloscope

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I add the two functions.

Comment: Start with this example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239296/, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85963/ for changing the color of the axis lines, add the option `axis lines=center` to the `axis` environment, and note that `pgfplots` by default uses degrees for trig functions (e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12956/).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'm going to try using these resources and post the result.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could alter this, with the equations you need?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=-4,%
        ymax=4,%
        grid=both,%
        %axis on top
        ]
     \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[blue,opacity=0.5] ({rel axis cs:0,0}) rectangle ({rel axis cs:1,1});

    \end{scope}
     \addplot[domain=-360:360, white , very thick, smooth]{sin(x)}; %add equation here
    \addplot[domain=-360:360, green , very thick, smooth]{2*cos(x)};% and here
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```